# Concatenate/append a single string in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I add a single string to one 'cell' on a dataframe in pandas?

I get the following error when I try the append command

"cannot concatenate object of type ''; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and _code_ for what you've tried so far. Also, since you have an error, please include the full error traceback in the text of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .iloc to locate the cell and += to append a string onto the end.

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c'])
df.iloc[0][0] += 'b'
```

Adds the letter 'b' to the first 'cell' in the dataframe.